# Replace number in word

Tags: java, string

How is it possible to replace every `1` with `one`, every `2` with `two`, every `3` with `three`...
 from an Input?

My Code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Text:");
        String Output;

        //replace
        Output = Input.replaceAll("1", "one");
        Output = Input.replaceAll("2", "two");

        //Output
        System.out.println(Output);
    }
}
```

It just work with one replace-item.

Comment: What is the context for the replacements?  Do you want to really replace _every_ digit `1` with `one`, even if the former appears inside a large number, e.g. `123`?

Comment: No. It schut work like that:

Comment: Input : 1 2     Output: one two

Comment: Please don't put additional information into comments, instead update your question.

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions. Variable names always *camelCase*. So `input` and `output`.

Answer (score 5):

You need call `replaceAll` on `OutPut` for the second time:

```
Output = Input.replaceAll("1", "one");
Output = Output.replaceAll("2", "two");
```

or just call `replaceAll` fluently:

```
Output = Input.replaceAll("1", "one").replaceAll("2", "two");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is setting `Output` twice using `Input` as the source string. Therefore, calling `Output = Input.replaceAll("2", "two);` completely negates the first time you called it.

You could replace that with this instead:

```
Output = Input.replaceAll("1", "one");
Output = Output.replaceAll("2", "two");
```

But that would be a bit excessive and become quite cumbersome if you want to define a lot of replacements.

---

Instead, you could use a `HashMap` to store the values you want to replace and what to replace them with.

Using `HashMap<Character, String>` allows you to store the single-character "key," or the value you want to replace, and its replacement string.

Then it is just a matter of reading each character of the input string and determining when the `HashMap` has defined a replacement for it.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    private static HashMap<Character, String> replacementMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Build the replacement strings
        replacementMap.put('1', "one");
        replacementMap.put('2', "two");
        replacementMap.put('3', "three");
        replacementMap.put('4', "four");
        replacementMap.put('5', "five");
        replacementMap.put('6', "six");
        replacementMap.put('7', "seven");
        replacementMap.put('8', "eight");
        replacementMap.put('9', "nine");
        replacementMap.put('0', "zero");

        String input = "This is 1 very long string. It has 3 sentences and 121 characters. Exactly 0 people will verify that count.";

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            // This character has a replacement defined in the map
            if (replacementMap.containsKey(c)) {
                // Add the replacement string to the output
                output.append(replacementMap.get(c));
            } else {
                // No replacement found, just add this character to the output
                output.append(c);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> This is one very long string. It has three sentences and onetwotwo characters. Exactly zero people will verify this count.

**Limitations:**

First of all, this implementation depends on your desired functionality and scope. Since there are an infinite number of possible numbers, this would not account for that.

Also, this looks for a single character to replace. If you wanted to expand this to replace "10" with "ten," for example, you would need to use `HashMap<String, String>` instead.

Unfortunately, your original question does not provide enough context in order to suggest the best way for you.